# Access a docker container in docker multi-host network

Tags: networking, docker

I have created a [Docker multi-host network](https://github.com/docker/dceu_tutorials/blob/94fd5f3e9372a8f58ca7b25f3232305731f7cd36/06-networking.md#task-2-configure-the-engine-to-use-key-value-store) using Docker Overlay network with 4 nodes: node0, node1, node2, and node3. Node0 act as key-value store which shares the information of nodes while  node1, node2, and node3 are bound to the key-value store.

[image]

Here are node1 networks:

```
user@node1$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER
04adb1ab4833        RED                 overlay             
 [ . . ]
```

As for node2 networks:

```
user@node2$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER
04adb1ab4833        RED                 overlay             
 [ . . ]
```

`container1` is running on node1, that hosts the RED-named network.

```
user@node1$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
f9bacac3c01d        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         3 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                    container1
```

Docker added an entry to /etc/hosts for each container that belongs to the RED overlay network.

```
user@node1$ docker exec container1 cat /etc/hosts

10.10.10.2  d82c36bc2659
127.0.0.1   localhost
 [ . . ]
10.10.10.3  container2
10.10.10.3  container2.RED
```

From node2, I'm trying to access the container1 running on node1. I tried to run container1 using command below but it returns error.

```
`user@node2$ docker docker exec -i -t container1 bash`
Error response from daemon: no such id: container1
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The network is shared only for the containers.

While the network is shared among the containers across the multi-hosts overlay, the docker daemons cannot communicate between them as is.

The `user@_node2_$ docker exec -i -t container1 bash` doest not work because, indeed, `no such id: container1` are running from **node2**.

#### Accessing remote Docker daemon

Docker daemons communicate through socket. UNIX socket by default, but it is possible to add an option, `--host` to specify other sockets the daemon should bind to.

See the `docker daemon` man page:

```
   -H, --host=[unix:///var/run/docker.sock]: tcp://[host:port] to bind or unix://[/path/to/socket] to use.
     The socket(s) to bind to in daemon mode specified using one or more
     tcp://host:port, unix:///path/to/socket, fd://* or fd://socketfd.
```

Thus, it is possible to access from any node a docker daemon bind to a tcp socket.

The command `user@node2$ docker -H tcp://node1:port exec -i -t container1 bash` would work well.

#### Docker and Docker cluster ([Swarm](http://docs.docker.com/swarm/))

I do not know what you are trying to deploy, maybe just playing around with the tutorials, and that's great! You may be interested to look into [Swarm](http://docs.docker.com/swarm/) that deploys a cluster of docker. In short: you can use several nodes as it they were one powerful docker daemon access through a single node with the whole Docker API.

Comment: Thanks. I' not using SWARM.

Comment: Tell me where I'm wrong please.
1. `container1` is run through node1 docker daemon.
2. `user@node1 $docker exec -i -t container1 bash` works.
3. `user@node2 $docker exec -i -t container1 bash` _does not_ works.

If all of these are right, the issue is that you try to execute a command from a node docker daemon that is not related with the other node docker daemon.

Note that if the containers share a common network and can communicate, this is not the case for daemon (especially with this form).

If it's right, I'll edit my answer to answer your question.

Comment: I edited your question (to make it shorter and removed some irrelevant details) and my answer. If my answer edit please you, I suggest you to tag your question as answered.